# how to get the connection status of client for activemq?

Tags: connection, client, activemq-classic

how to get the connection status of client for activemq? if A and B are connected with server, a momnet later, how can A know B's status?

Answer (score 1):

You can either, from A, subscribe to [advisory messages](http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html) to get an idea of status changes, or you can use [JMX](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html) to find out which clients are connected.

The idea with loose coupling is that you should not need to know if the other client is online, since the middleware takes care store and forward.

Comment: Is there any recent updates about how to know that a user is online or offline ?